# How can I access the class method after had the instance?

Tags: flutter, dart

When I try to access `toJson()` I get `Object.noSuchMethod`.

This is my follow class:

```
class MyClass {
  int offset;
  String tag;

  MyClass(
      {offset,
      tag}) {
    this.offset = offset;
    this.tag = tag;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    var args = {
      'offset': offset > 0 ? offset.toString() : null,
      'tag': tag,
    };
    args.removeWhere((key, value) => value == null);
    return args;
  }
}
```

I also have a sevice class

```
class MyClasService {
  static Future<List<Something>> getAll([MyClass args]) async {
    try {
      Iterable res = await HttpService.get('posts', args.toJson());
      // Iterable res = await HttpService.get('posts');
      return res.map((model) => Post.fromJson(model)).toList();
    } catch (e) {
      return [];
    }
  }
}
```

And the service call

```
PagewiseListView(
    pageSize: PAGE_SIZE,
    itemBuilder: (context, Post item, _) => MyComponent(item: item),
    pageFuture: (pageIndex) => MyClassService.getAll(
        new MyClass(page: pageIndex * PAGE_SIZE, perPage: PAGE_SIZE)));
```

When I try to call `args.toJson()` then I got the exception.

> NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method '>' was called on
>   null.\nReceiver: null\nTried calling: >(0))

But if I just call `Iterable res = await HttpService.get('posts');` it works.

I thought that the problem was with my `(new MyClass()).toJson()`, but if I call only if, removing the http request, also no errors.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code, the problem is not related the code you shared.

Comment: @EsenMehmet, indeed. Well seems that the problem is call with async (see the update) but still can't figure it out.

Comment: The problem was the `'offset': offset > 0 ? offset.toString() : null,` I had also to check if it was null `'offset': offset != null && offset > 0 ? offset.toString() : null,`